# How to specify weight to colors in stripped style in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

In the [Graphviz's documentation](https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/style/), it is said about the `striped` style that:

> Optional color weights can be specified to indicate the proportional widths of the bars.

But there is not any other detail about this feature. How do you specify it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the first couple of sentences in the "colorlist" documentation https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/colorList/
An example:

```
digraph{
  node[shape=rect]
  subgraph clusterX{
  graph [style="striped" color="purple" fillcolor="aqua;.7:pink"]
  a [style="striped" color="red" fillcolor="green;.2:blue;.2:yellow"]
  b [style="striped" color="green" fillcolor="green;.8:blue;.1:yellow"]
  b -> a [color="red;.5:blue;.2:orange"]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I missed this part of the documentation, thanks !